# How to redirect to an another route when the user select a rate from a select tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple web app using flask and I added a simple rating system using the select tag. My question is how I go to another route once the user select a number from the dropdown menu and also know which number they choosed.

```
<label class="custom-select">
Give your rate
<select class="custom-select" 
style="width:200px;" id="example">
 <option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option> <option 
value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
</label>
```

Comment: you may redirect using `JavaScript` once the selected item on the dropdown changes. Also, you may put that dropdown in a `form` element and let that form handle the redirection either by triggering the `form`'s submit event by `JavaScript` or by adding a submit button along that dropdown.

Comment: You probably want to have a look into "Ajax". Here is one of many examples in the net: https://www.datasciencelearner.com/python-ajax-json-request-form-flask/ -- submit the data via Javascript and implement an endpoint for getting the data and redirecting according to it.